# python program with unexpected output

Tags: python

please help, i am stuck----
my python program--

```
input1=raw_input("please enter the message :")
bajaj_bikes_regx= re.compile("(www)*")#|((cbr){0,4}\s{0,4}([0125r\s]{0,8}))",re.I) 
truck_regx= re.compile("truc*k",re.I)               

bajaj_bikes= (bajaj_bikes_regx.search(input1)).group(0)
print (bajaj_bikes)

truck= (truck_regx.search(input1)).group(0)
print (truck)
```

when i input the string as --- www truck , the output comes as required, however when i input the string as truck www , the output comes as truck only and www doesn;t gets printed. please help me

Comment: Your regex has an extra `"` in it. Fix that first and then update your post.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: If my answer helps, please confirm it so that anyone else could find this answer easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shold use `bajaj_bikes_regx= re.compile("(www)$")`